# Why are my SharedPreferences entries not being cleared upon reinstalling?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, sharedpreferences

Upon reinstalling my app the code within my if statement is being accessed despite my SharedPreferences entry not yet having been created. I'm using an emulator with eclipse, does the data need to be cleared some other way than reinstalling? Thanks

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("appData", 0);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String gsonStr = prefs.getString("playerString", null);

        if(gsonStr != null)
        {
            //This code is being accessed on the apps first onCreate() call prior to being reinstalled 
            Player[] tempArray = gson.fromJson(gsonStr, Player[].class);
            Log.d("First Player", "" + tempArray[0]);
        }

protected void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    if(savedPlayers != null)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String gsonStr = gson.toJson(savedPlayers.toArray());

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("appData", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        //editor().clear();
        Log.d("GSONString",gson.toString());
        editor.putString("playerString", gsonStr);
        editor.putInt("ArraySize", savedPlayers.size());
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the app is simply being reinstalled. In order for the data to be cleared, the app actually has to be uninstalled first. Reinstalling won't actually clear the data. The emulator actually allows for a runtime option that will wipe all user data when you run the emulator, but I don't believe it runs each time your run the app. You can set this option in the Run Configurations for the app if you are using eclipse.

To do it from inside the emulator, go to settings->applications->manage applications->your app->clear data

Comment: RunConfigurations > Wipe User Data does the job.

Comment: Ach must be something else that damned if statement is still letting me past.

Comment: What api level of emulator are you using?

Comment: Nevermind was a problem with my code.
Regardless of whether I saved any players to the savedPlayers ArrayList it was being added to SharedPreferences when onPause() was being called. I've replaced savedPlayeres!=null with savedPlayer.size() > 0

Comment: On a real device, Is the data going to be cleared when ever the App is updated through the store?? 
If not, How can I make it to clear data or at least clear the preferences file on each update?

Answer (score 3):

A shared preference and sqlite db doesnt get removed on a  reinstall. To delete them, go to **Settings-->Appications-->Manage Applications-->Click on you application-->Click on "Clear Data"** on emulator. this will clear the data stored.

Comment: Oh wait you meant on the emulator. I was looking on Eclipse.

Comment: When on your home screen, click on the button which shows u the list of application. One among them is Settings

Comment: Only options I can see are Uninstall,  Clear Cache (unselectable), Clear Defaults (unselectable), Force Stop.